# How to get picture current frames from video file in Livecode?

Tags: video-capture, snapshot, livecode

I don't sure from my question has possibilities. If possible I want to create pictures from video file.
If impossible. Can you suggest for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to assign the video to a player object, set the visible of the players controller to false and then use the following script-

```
import snapshot from player "name of your player"
```

What this does is take a snapshot of the current frame of the player and place it as an image object on your stack